# indexing column name in the dataframe in r

Tags: r, indexing

```
> df
  A B C
1 1 2 3
2 4 5 6
3 7 8 9
```

This is an example from another stack over flow question.
Actually, in my dataset, there are 301 columns.

I wonder How I can index the column name.
For example, I want to extract A, B, and C as my 1st, 2nd, and 3rd columns in the df.

```
df[0,1]
```

I thought it would give me "A" because it is the first column's name.
but the result was Not "A" but

```
numeric(0)
```

How can I index my column name by its location? (1st, 2nd, 3rd ... columns in the dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R indexing starts from 1 (and not 0). Secondly, `df` is the dataframe to get the names of the columns you need to index `names(df)` or `colnames(df)`.

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 1:5, C = 1:5)

#To get all the column names
names(df)
#[1] "A" "B" "C"

#To get the 1st column name
names(df)[1]
#[1] "A"

#To get 1st and 2nd column name
names(df)[1:2]
#[1] "A" "B"

#To get column names 1 to 3
names(df)[1:3]
#[1] "A" "B" "C"

#To get column names 1 and 3
names(df)[c(1, 3)]
#[1] "A" "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively via `select()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(1,3) %>% colnames()
```